# MVC 4 converts a Dictionary to RouteValueDictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm experiencing problems passing data in a Dictionary object to the CreateUserAndAccount method in a custom ExtendedMembershipProvider. In my Account controller, the (Post) Register method has the following:

```
Dictionary<string, object> userInfo = new Dictionary<string, object>();

userInfo.Add("Email", model.Email);
userInfo.Add("PasswordQuestion", model.PasswordQuestion);
userInfo.Add("PasswordAnswer", model.PasswordAnswer);

WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password, userInfo, true);
```

Which populates userInfo and succesfully calls the CreateUserAndAccount method in my custom provider.

I have two - maybe connected - problems.

Firstly, the method signatures are not the same, the provider method looks like this:

```
public override string CreateUserAndAccount(string userName, string password, bool requireConfirmation, IDictionary<string, object> values)
```

The Boolean and Dictionary parameters are switched over, but the method is still reached. If I change the code in the Account/Register method to match this I get:

> The best overloaded method match for
>   WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(string, string,
>   object, bool)' has some invalid arguments.

I am confused as to how this can occur, my question is basically what on earth is going on?

Secondly, when the code reaches CreateUserAndAccount, the Dictionary object I passed to it has been converted to a RouteValueDictionary, all the other parameters appear as expected.

How can I get my Dictionary object back out and access the Email, PasswordQuestion, and PasswordAnswer values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature of [the static `WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.websecurity.createuserandaccount%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) doesn't match the signature of [the `ExtendedMembershipProvider.CreateUserAndAccount` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg569445%28v=vs.111%29.aspx). You can't call one method using the other's signature, which is why you're getting the compiler error when you try.

The method on the `WebSecurity` class explicitly converts the `propertyValues` parameter to a `RouteValueDictionary`, because it's designed to accept any object, whereas the `ExtendedMembershipProvider` method expects an `IDictionary<string, object>` parameter.

For example, you could pass in an anonymous object and the call would still work:

```
WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password,
   new { model.Email, model.PasswordQuestion, model.PasswordAnswer },
   true);
```

Comment: Thanks Richard, great answer.

TBH I should have spotted that myself, end of a long coding session...